# Using map to map to property in rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I was checking the ngrx docs, and I noticed the following code

```
  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LoginPageActions.login),
      map(action => action.credentials),
      exhaustMap((auth: Credentials) =>
        this.authService.login(auth).pipe(
          // more code..
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

I am just wondering, what is the point of that `map(action => action.credentials),`? Cant we just use the payload directly in the `exhaustMap` without the extra `map`? like this:

```
  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LoginPageActions.login),
      exhaustMap((login: LoginAction) =>
        this.authService.login(login.credentials).pipe(
          // more code..
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: Have you tried this particular piece of code? i.e. does what you're suggesting work? If it does, then it is purely business best practice, if it doesn't then it is an underlying requirement in order to use the NGRX `createEffect` correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can use it as you mentioned.
also you could use destructuring

```
login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LoginPageActions.login),
      exhaustMap(({credentials}) =>
        this.authService.login(credentials).pipe(
          // more code..
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

or if you have more properties:

```
login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LoginPageActions.login),
      exhaustMap(({credentials, flags}) =>
        this.authService.login(credentials, flags).pipe(
          // more code..
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what is exactly the point of the docs using the `map` operator there? Did it add any functionality / logic?

Comment: Nothing special. Just a way how the author wrote the doc. you can skip the `map` if you feel it's redundant.